# “Personal address detected. Import the collectible contract address” error while importing an NFT from Opensea

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, metamask

Let me share my problem in short here.

So I did a course on Buildspace that was on [*Creating your first smart contract*](https://buildspace.so/p/CO02cf0f1c-f996-4f50-9669-cf945ca3fb0b).

On completing it, I got a [*Buildspace NFT*](https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0x3CD266509D127d0Eac42f4474F57D0526804b44e/19238?force_update=true) from their side but **I was not able to import it on my Metamask account**. This is the error I was getting while importing it:

[image]

**Does anyone know how to import an NFT from Opensea account?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the above issue I've searched on internet but didn't able to find anything to resolve this issue.

So, I've been to MetaMask support and they helped me out instantly. Here's what the actual problem was and what they did to resolve the issue.

**Actual problem**: I was importing a Polygon NFT on an Ethereum Network.
**Solution**: I had to change my Network from Ethereum to Polygon!
So, to switch from the Ethereum Network to Polygon (MATIC) Network in MetaMask, you have to

**On Mobile:**

> 1. Got to Settings
> 2. Click on Networks
> 3. Click on "Add Network"

**On Personal Computer:**

> 1. Click on MetaMask extension
> 2. Click the dropdown where "Ethereum Mainnet" is written
> 3. Click on "Add Network"

**Now, fill up these details**:

> Network Name: **Polygon Mainnet**
> RPC Url: **https://polygon-rpc.com/**
> Chain ID: **137**
> Symbol: **MATIC**
> Block Explorer URL: **https://polygonscan.com/**

Then hit "Add".
That's all you have to do. Now you can go ahead with the same process of importing your brand new NFT to your MetaMask wallet. Yayy!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are on a correct network, e.g. if contract is deployed on goerli test-network then network to goerli test-network.
there are various types of networks are present there in metamask mobile app, select correct network and paste correct contract address

[image: metamask app network options]